# Changing scale of the ROC chart

Tags: r, roc, proc-r-package

I am using the following code to plot the ROC curve after having run the logistic regression.

```
fit1 <- glm(formula=GB160M3~Behvscore, data=eflscr,family="binomial", na.action = na.exclude)
prob1=predict(fit1, type=c("response"))
eflscr$prob1 = prob1

library(pROC)
g1 <- roc(GB160M3~prob1, data=eflscr, plot=TRUE,  grid=TRUE, print.auc=TRUE)
```

The ROC curves plotted look like this (see link below)

[image]

1. The x-axis scale does not fill the who chart.
2. How can I change the x axis to report 1 - specifically?

Comment: Note that question 1 is addressed in more details specifically in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42057979/proc-roc-curves-remove-empty-space

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. By default pROC sets `asp = 1` to ensure the plot is square and both sensitivity and specificity are on the same scale. You can set it to `NA` or `NULL` to free the axis and fill the chart, but your ROC curve will be misshaped.

   ```
   plot(g1, asp = NA)
   ```

   Using `par(pty="s")` as suggested by Joe is probably a better approach
2. This is purely a labeling problem: note that the x axis goes decreasing from 1 to 0, which is exactly the same as plotting 1-specificity on an increasing axis. You can set the `legacy.axes` argument to `TRUE` to change the behavior if the default one bothers you.

   ```
   plot(g1, legacy.axes = TRUE)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

A good shortcut to getting a square plot is to run the following before plotting:

```
par(pty="s")
```

This forces the shape of the plot region to be square. Set the plotting region back to maximal by simply resetting the graphics device and clearing the plot.

```
dev.off()
```

As pointed out by @Calimo, there is the `legacy.axes` argument to reverse the x-axis and the label is also changed automatically. You can run `?plot.roc` to see all the pROC plotting options.

**Example**

```
# Get ROC object
data(aSAH)
roc1 <- roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$s100b)

# Plot
par(pty="s")
plot(roc1, grid = TRUE, legacy.axes = TRUE)

# Reset graphics device and clear plot
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thank you Joe. Let me try this

Comment: One additional question. How do I change the actual scale. At the moment it it in descending order from 1 to 0. I want it from 0 to 1.

Comment: The x axis in the OP's figure really *is* the specificity. Labeling it 1-Sp would be misleading without also reversing the axis.

Comment: Agreed with@Calimo. Just forcing the label to change would be misleading. Never do that. Rather change the scale from 0 to 1 (increasing order) by using legacy. axis argument.

Comment: legacy. axis takes value TRUE or FALSE(Default) indicating if the specificity axis (x axis) must be plotted as as decreasing “specificity” (FALSE, the default) or increasing “1 - specificity” (TRUE) as in most legacy software. This affects only the axis, not the plot coordinates

Comment: @Joe, please also tell how to reset the plot setting after using par(pty="s") for this plot?

Comment: `par(pty="m")`. I've added it to the answer above.

Comment: Actually you can also just reset the graphics device `dev.off()` as well.