# pROC ROC curves remove empty space

Tags: axis-labels, roc, proc-r-package

I want to draw ROC curves with pRoC.
However for some reason there is extra empty space on either side of the x-axis and I cannot remove it with xlim. Some example code:

```
library(pROC)
n = c(4, 3, 5) 
b = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) 
df = data.frame(n, b) 
rocobj <- plot.roc(df$b, df$n, percent = TRUE, main="ROC", col="#1c61b6", add=FALSE)
```

[image]

I tried the pROC help file, but that doesn't really help me. Even more puzzling is to me that the Y-axis is OK looking...

I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the plotting device is square and adjust the margins so that top + bottom == left + right:

```
library(pROC)
png("test.png", width = 480, height = 480)
par(mar = c(4, 4, 4, 4)+.1)
n = c(4, 3, 5) 
b = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
rocobj <- plot.roc(b, n, percent = TRUE, main="ROC", col="#1c61b6", add=FALSE)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Calimo, thans for your help! This seems to work. However, is there a way to fix this without first writing the plot to a file (aka just inside R)?

Comment: You should be able to do that with your interactive device as well. `getOption("device")(width = ..., height = ...)`

Answer (score 2):

An other answer, if you don't mind to have distorted axis, is to use the `asp` parameter. By default it is set to 1, ensuring both axis have the same scale and the ROC curve is squared*, but you can turn it off with `asp = NA`:

```
library(pROC)
par(mar = c(4, 4, 4, 4)+.1)
n = c(4, 3, 5) 
b = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
rocobj <- plot.roc(b, n, percent = TRUE, main="ROC", col="#1c61b6", add=FALSE, asp = NA)
```

[image]

<sub>* Having a squared ROC curve is important if you want to interpret it visually. For instance, you may want to compare several local maximas by their distance to the diagonal: you can only do that if the two axis have the same scale. So if you want to do that make sure to follow my other answer.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

There is yet a third answer, which takes the margins out of the plotting region, so it will automatically look squared, even when the device isnt. This is done by setting the [graphical parameter](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html) `pty` to `"s"`:

```
library(pROC)
par(pty = "s")
n = c(4, 3, 5) 
b = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
rocobj <- plot.roc(b, n, percent = TRUE, main="ROC", col="#1c61b6", add=FALSE, asp = NA)
```

[image]

(I added a black frame to visualize what's going on)