# R base graphics plots roc with big internal margins

Tags: r, graphics, roc

I just plotted an ROC curve using pROC::roc as follows

```
plot(roc(mlabs, yhat, direction="<"), 
     col="blue", lwd=3, main = paste0("ROC Curves for Model ", mname), xlim = c(1, 0), ylim = c(0, 1))
```

and got a result with wide margins on either side of xlim. These make it hard to visually assess the model (i.e. the curve looks much further from top-left corner than it really is).

I don't think I've seen base graphics apply such large internal margins before. Is there any way to control it?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a data by pasting the output of `dput(df)` where `df` is your data set?

Comment: This question has already been asked, and I gave two possible answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42057979/proc-roc-curves-remove-empty-space