# plotting ROC problems with axes limits. R plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, roc

Well, i've been trying to make a plot with my ROCS in a particular fashion so it matches the style of publications my colleagues are doing.

[image: Example of what i want to get]

But everytime i do my ROCS i cant even manage to reduce my axis, ( i tried several changes in xlim), nor i obtain the "box-like" border of the graphs. I tried following these tutorials

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qcvAqAH60Yw
https://rdrr.io/cran/pROC/man/ggroc.html

but i dont obtain anything, and ggroc refuses to works saying my dimensions are not correct (Even with the example provided by the page).

I just obtained this with my data:

[image]

But if i change my xlim to 0,1

[image]

Doesnt work. And i have tried several combinations of it.

Any ideas?

In order to provide some code, lets work with ASAH data.

[image]

And we get the same problems with the plot in pROC if we do it.

[image]

Could you lend me a hand with this, honorable community of stack?
Edit: So far, so good with this. But i still have the problems of the axis, wich i want them to start as the first image as reference that i posted.

With ggplot2 i think i cand do it, tho, thanks to an answer provided.

[image]

Comment: This should answer your question [pROC ROC curves remove empty space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42057979/proc-roc-curves-remove-empty-space)

Comment: If not then please edit this one to highlight what is still unclear.

Comment: Very useful, but i still got that tiny space between my "function" (roc) and the axis. ¿Is there a way i can force it as my first image? @Calimo

Comment: Please edit your question with what you have now.

Comment: Also I don't see why you tagged the question with ggplot2. Can you clarify that too? Do you specifically want an answer with ggplot2?

Comment: Not really, i just see that is the most common library for plots and i just tagged it, my bad. Will edit in a minute, i just re-run my rmd and everything went bollocks, every number changed despise my set.seed.

Comment: Done, @Calimo. Thanks in advance :D. I think i can do it with ggplot2, but im in the procces of doing it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(pROC)

#some data
data(aSAH)

# store roc object 
roc.ob <- roc(outcome ~ s100b, aSAH)

ggroc(roc.ob, legacy.axes = T) +
geom_abline(slope = 1 ,intercept = 0) + # add identity line
theme(
panel.background = element_blank(), 
axis.title.x = element_text(size =18, face = 'bold'),
axis.title.y = element_text(size =18, face = 'bold'),
panel.border = element_rect(size = 2, fill = NA), 
axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14, face ='bold'),
axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14, face ='bold')) +
xlab('100% - Specificity') +
ylab('100% - Sensitivity') +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1,0.25), labels = seq(0,1,0.25) * 100) + 
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1,0.25), labels = seq(0,1,0.25) * 100)
```

Comment: This works quite fine, thank you. There still a problem with the x.axis values, because we say 100%-specificity and it keeps starting at 100. ¿Is there a way i can change that? ¿Is there a way i can plot the AUC value in the same plot? Or even plotting various ROCS there?. Im looking for tutorials on ggplot themes :D, seems quite useful. @e.matt

Comment: Updated with axes work around which may help

Comment: Thank you ! Had to adapt the code to: 

scale_x_continuous(breaks = (seq(0,1,0.25)*100)-100, labels = seq(0,1,0.25) * 100) + 
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1,0.25)*100, labels = seq(0,1,0.25) * 100)

But now it works perfectly! @e.matt