# The axis of ROC multiplot is being weird when saved as pdf in studio

Tags: r, logistic-regression, roc

I am new to R and coding. I am trying to save a multiplot as a pdf or a jpeg. But when I do the

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev = "tiff",
                      dpi = 500)

pdf("ROCplots.pdf")
par(mfrow=c(1,2))

# ROC plot 1
roc(na.exclude(Data$Disease), glmbas$fitted.values, plot=TRUE, legacy.axes=FALSE, percent=TRUE, col="skyblue3", lty="solid", lwd=2, print.auc=FALSE)
plot.roc(na.exclude(Data$Disease),  glmadv$fitted.values, percent=TRUE, col="skyblue3", lty="longdash", lwd=2, print.auc=FALSE, add=TRUE)

legend("bottomright", c("Adv 1 (AUC = 0.89)", "Bas 1 (AUC = 0.81)"),
        col = c("skyblue3", "skyblue3"), lty=c("longdash", "solid"), lwd=2, cex = 0.45)

title(main = "A) Bas-Adv 1", line = 2.5, cex=4)

# ROC plot 2
roc(na.exclude(Data$Disease), glmbas4$fitted.values, plot=TRUE, legacy.axes=FALSE, percent=TRUE, col="skyblue3", lty="solid", lwd=2, print.auc=FALSE)
plot.roc(na.exclude(Data$Disease),  glmadv4$fitted.values, percent=TRUE, col="skyblue3", lty="longdash", lwd=2, print.auc=FALSE, add=TRUE)

legend("bottomright", c("Adv 4 (AUC = 0.83)", "bas 4 (AUC = 0.73)"),
        col = c("skyblue3", "skyblue3"), lty=c("longdash", "solid"), lwd=2, cex = 0.45)

title(main = "B)Bas-Adv 4", line = 2.5, cex=4)


dev.off()
```

It comes out with weird axes. Please see in the attached image. I have tried everything recommended online. I have played with height and width and still the axis are wrong. I want the axis to be : x= 100 to 0 with 20 as the gap between the points (Specificity %); the y-axis to be = 0 to 100 with 20 as the gap. [image]

In the code itself, the plots turn out fine. Please see the attached screenshot.[image] They get wonky when I save them as a pdf or jpeg.

I would really appreciate the help. also how can I set the pdf image width to 255 pts.

Comment: you have to set the height/width of the device `pdf("ROCplots.pdf", height = 5, width = 12)`

Comment: See also the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/42057979/333599